# Video Tag Not Working On Mobile

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, html, video

I have an ASP website that plays a video depending on the HTTP parameter `'id'`

Server side:

```
  Public vidurl As String
  Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim id As String = Request.QueryString("id")
        Dim DT As New DataTable
        Dim vidInfo As VideoInfo
        Try


            If id IsNot Nothing Then

                Dim SQLConnection_Cont As New SqlConnection(SQLConntStr)
                DT = f.GetVideoInfo(id, SQLConnection_Cont)

                If DT IsNot Nothing Then
                    If DT.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                        vidInfo = New VideoInfo With {
                             .ID = DT.Rows(0).Item("FTPID"),
                             .Processed = DT.Rows(0).Item("Processed"),
                             .URL = DT.Rows(0).Item("URL"),
                             .VideoName = DT.Rows(0).Item("VideoName"),
                             .VidID = DT.Rows(0).Item("VidID"),
                             .Created = DT.Rows(0).Item("Created"),
                             .MonthDiff = DT.Rows(0).Item("Monthdiff")}


                        If vidInfo.MonthDiff = 0 Then
                            vidurl = "http://webpath.com/virtualdirectory/content/" & vidInfo.VideoName
                           End If
                    End If
                End If 
          End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            WriteExToFile("Video.aspx.vb", ex.ToString)
        End Try

    End Sub
```

Client Side:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Video Player</title>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
        <div id="vidplay">
            <video height="400"  controls style="position: relative; top: 23px;">
                 <source src=<%= vidurl %>  type="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"/>
                 <object data=src=<%= vidurl %> width="320" height="240"></object> 
            </video>
       </div>
       </div>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

So I am passing the video path in the virtual directory in the global variable `vidurl`

When I play this on Google Chrome for Desktop, I only hear the sound in the video, with a black image.

When I play it on mobile, a black video appears, but It doesn't play anything at all.

What can be the problem?

**Please note that all the videos in the virtual directory are in mp4 format.**

**UPDATE:**

I went to the **Codec Information** in my Video,

It says : `MPEG-4 Video (mp4v)`

Could that be the problem?

Priority is for the video to work on mobiles.

Comment: Can you put a public link to a short/small test video clip? Usually sound with no video means that at least Chrome understood the **audio codec** part but not the **video codec** hence sound with no picture. About mobile, does that mean Android or iOS? I think iOS only wants MP4 with AAC sound (not MP3)

Comment: Most likely, clips doesn't work on mobiles, Just copy clips to mobile for testing directly.

Comment: @nghiavt Im sorry can you explain more?

Comment: Can you remove the codec and see if that helps ( let browser to choose wahtever coded needed) . Have you tried opening that video file directly in chrome? does that play, if so, then it should work with `<video>` tag. For mobile do the same thing, may be mobile needs entirely different formatted video like `m4v` .

Comment: @HelpASisterOut i mean: copy your video clip  on your phone to make sure it could play first.

Comment: @nghiavt Hi, copying the video file to my phone, it played with no problem

Comment: @ArindamNayak  i tried dragging and dropping the video in chrome, it played the sound only

Comment: Ok, then video has issue in itself, you need to check the same video with any player ( like VLC, windows media etc..), If so, get a video that plays in video player and in browser, then start using/experimenting with that video in your application.

Comment: Which mobile platform?

Comment: @HelpASisterOut Please accept the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 3):

Some file formats are not supported on some browsers. Try adding additional sources of web video formats.

```
<source src="somevideo.webm" type="video/webm">
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately playing video across all the browsers is pain in the ***. For me solution that still works the best is [mediaelement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/) (even ie8). Set up is quite easy and is quite brodly used library recommended by the best brains in front end world. The only problem is that is really hard to make it responsive when using flash fallback.

Even when you supply all the possible formats you still will see multiple issues like giving wrong time of video, different control options across devices. Also some converters don't work well when it comes to keeping standards for web. the best one for me is http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/ for mac. Also  support of formats/codecs varies depending on browse * operation system * installed programmes so is always good to use something as fallback (flash).

There are few other newer libraries you can use other then mediaelement, but in my test most of them worked quite poorly. The best one was video.js (polyfill alike) and popcorn player.

Answer (score 0):

well, i don't know if your code is the same as your sample code, but here are some suggestions you can try based on your sample code

```
<video height="400"  controls style="position: relative; top: 23px;">
   <source src="<%= vidurl %>" type="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"/>
   <object data-src="<%= vidurl %>" width="320" height="240"></object> 
</video>
```

1. enclose your `<%= vidurl %>` with quotes
2. change your object `data=src` to `data-src`

hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just add `playsinline` attribute in video tag.

```html
<video playsinline autoplay loop muted style="min-width:100%; min-height:100%;" >
  <source type="video/mp4" src="//bg.cdn.ustudio.com/app/transcodes/TQAdh6DJdtuY.mp4">
  <source type="video/webm" src="//bg.cdn.ustudio.com/app/transcodes/TuX1xml2yZsS.webm">
</video>
```